# How to retrieve images from Instagram which has special hashtag?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, instagram

My client wants to share an image on Instagram. I have implemeted sharing image on instagram.But i could not share it with a special hashtag. Here is my code so far.

```
- (IBAction)sharePhotoOnInstagram:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *imgpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgpicker.delegate=self;
    [self storeimage];
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
    {

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 612, 612);
        NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/15717.ig"];

        NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
        dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
        dic.delegate = self;
        dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
        dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
        dic.delegate = self;
        [dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: self.view animated: YES ];
        //  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    }
    else
    {
        //   NSLog(@"instagramImageShare");
        UIAlertView *errorToShare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instagram unavailable " message:@"You need to install Instagram in your device in order to share this image" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        errorToShare.tag=3010;
        [errorToShare show];
    }
}


- (void) storeimage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"15717.ig"];
    UIImage *NewImg = [self resizedImage:picTaken :CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 612) ];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(NewImg);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}

-(UIImage*) resizedImage:(UIImage *)inImage: (CGRect) thumbRect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [inImage CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    // There's a wierdness with kCGImageAlphaNone and CGBitmapContextCreate
    // see Supported Pixel Formats in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide
    // Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context section
    // only RGB 8 bit images with alpha of kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,
    // and kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, with a few other oddball image kinds are supported
    // The images on input here are likely to be png or jpeg files
    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    // Build a bitmap context that's the size of the thumbRect
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                NULL,
                                                thumbRect.size.width,       // width
                                                thumbRect.size.height,      // height
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),   // really needs to always be 8
                                                4 * thumbRect.size.width,   // rowbytes
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                alphaInfo
                                                );

    // Draw into the context, this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, thumbRect, imageRef);

    // Get an image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef  ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage*    result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);   // ok if NULL
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;
}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate
{  
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = self;

    return interactionController;
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerWillPresentOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{

}

- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller canPerformAction:(SEL)action
{
    //    NSLog(@"5dsklfjkljas");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller performAction:(SEL)action
{ 
    //    NSLog(@"dsfa");
    return YES;
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
    //    NSLog(@"fsafasd;");
}
```

**Note : This is working fine.**

I have followed their documentation on **http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/** but couldn't get better idea from it!. Now don't know what to do next step for sharing an image with hashtag and other information.

**Secondly** I want to retrieve all the images shared with a particular hashtag into the application.

Please guide me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from [iPhone Hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/), under 'Document Interaction':

> To include a pre-filled caption with your photo, you can set the annotation property on the document interaction request to an NSDictionary containing an NSString under the key "InstagramCaption". Note: this feature will be available on Instagram 2.1 and later.

You'll need to add something like:

```
dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"#yourTagHere" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
```

Second, you'll need to take a look at [Tag Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) if you want to pull down images with a specific tag.

Comment: Thanks you Kyle! Thankx alot. Can we retrieve multiple images shared with the same tag by different users?